# Record and replay interactions with a webpage

Tags: java, testing, selenium, integration-testing

I am currently implementing integration test for a complex website.

I write tests by hand that simulate various events on the pages, check the value of various elements and check that everything fine by storing screenshots. The server requests are mocked.

This works quite well, but the process of writing the tests takes a lot of time.

**Instead I want to record my interactions with the page then be able to replay them.**

I want to record:

- the events that are generated
- the network requests and their responses, so I can mock them later
- the value of and positions of some fields displayed on the page (could be hand-picked)

**Is there any such tool?** I am writing a Firefox plugin for that but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Google for "import.io"

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin i use:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

It has record function, you can then export it and run it as a test.

When you right click an element on the page you can also assert on this in various ways.

Hope this is what you were looking for,